# Matching timestamped GPS points to a path that has no timestamps

Tags: algorithms

I have two data sources available - one is timestamped GPS points, and another is a path fitted to roads, without timestamps (although points are ordered).

What I need is to combine the data sources into a fitted path, that has interpolated timestamps based on the raw GPS points. Current attempts at an algorithm have not worked - it fails on edge cases such as sharp corners or paths that cross.

Is there an algorithm or some sort of math that I can use to do this? Something like minimising the sum of errors between GPS points and fitted paths, while keeping the points in order. I'm not sure how to translate this to a mathematical formula/algorithm however.